# third party packages work without node_modules folder?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When we push our code `Github` or any remote repository service, we push everything without the `node_modules` folder.

The question is: how do all the third-party libraries work in the hosted website since the `node_modules` folder wasn't added and all the libraries are dependent on the `node_modules` folder?

I have been wondering for a long time now.

Comment: In order to execute that code you need to run `npm install`. That step can be automated. You also need to understand the difference between code repository and hosting service. The former is just where the code is stored, together with all its history, and the latter is the one specific version of the code is executed and exposed to the outer world through a network port.

Comment: I didn't pay enough attention to the React tag. There's server-side JavaScript (e.g. Node) and client-side JavaScript (e.g. Chrome or Firefox). Some times (as here) the former is used to generate the latter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create your production build, the needed node_modules are build into a single js file (depending on your configuration ofc), so once you've got the production build, that includes everything for the site to work.

You don't push the node_module to GIT because it's reproducible by running eg `npm install` after cloning the project, no need to save such data to GIT.

Answer (score 1):

Every `libraries` that needs to be installed is included in the `package.json` file. Upon deploying your application, there will a build step in which the libraries will be installed by simply running `npm start` which installs the `libraries` listed in the `package.json` file.

So no need to include such huge `node_modules` folder as it can be reproduced.